# Database lazy fetch

Tags: java, sql

i have a simple database   one-directionnel-relationthip :

```
public class Bill{

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn( name="BILL_ACTOR" )
    private fr.teamwill.cbm.model.actor.Actor actor;
}
```

i need to get the email of the actor, but when i do this i get an exception about lazy:

```
bill.getActor().getEmail() ---> exception
```

PLease can you give me sql requete to get the actor , i am a bit weak in database ,  here is wat i think of:

```
select a.email  From Bill b , Actor a fetch  join  ?????? or inner join??
```

Please give me the requete and thank you alot

Comment: you can enable hibernate sql trace and see the sql log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG will enable the sql trace.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the actor data because you've set it as a LAZY fetch type.

For your requested query, it can be

```
SELECT a.email  
FROM Bill b, Actor a 
WHERE b.BILL_ACTOR = a.id
```

---

I am curious why you're setting the LAZY fetch type for this attribute.

As usual, LAZY mode should be applied for heavily loading data. In your case, it should be applied for `bills` attribute in the `Actor` class.
Here is an example

```
public class Bill {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name="BILL_ACTOR" )
  private fr.teamwill.cbm.model.actor.Actor actor;
}

public class Actor {
   //...
   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<Bill> bills

}
```

Comment: Marking ManyToOnes as lazy fetched it is a viable strategy if there are going to be thousands of instances of the parent entity fetched and the children are only rarely actually referenced.

Comment: It was clearly mentioned that it is `uni-directional` relationship. So why do you put bills in `Actor` class? @Tran Ho